# Commented lines in imported text file

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a SQL script similar to this:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'legends.txt' INTO TABLE legends
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

The text file being imported looks something like this:

```
\N  248 1   Some text
\N  248 3   More text
\N  248 4   A line of text
\N  248 6   Lots of words
```

My question is, can I have commented lines in the imported text file? For instance, I would like to have the column names at the top of the text file like this:

```
PK  FK1 FK2 Description
\N  248 1   Some text
\N  248 3   More text
\N  248 4   A line of text
\N  248 6   Lots of words
```

Comment: You can add `IGNORE 1 LINES` to the end of your query to get it to skip the first line in  the file.

Comment: That is a good solution, but a dangerous one in case I forget. I am editing many of the text files by hand. Can I rely on MySQL throwing an error, such as a wrong data type?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way of telling `LOAD DATA INFILE` to skip lines other than lines at the beginning.

Comment: There is no `COMMENTS INITIATED BY` command?

Comment: @posfan12 it would be relatively easy for you to check the mysql manual for the various parameters that load data infile supports... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: `LINES STARTING BY` seems like it might do the opposite of what I need. I don't understand the rest of the help document.

Comment: @Nick I will mark your answer as correct since it's the best one.

Comment: It would seem you could use the `IGNORE` option (i.e. `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'legends.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE legends`) since you are using `LOCAL`, as long as your comment lines don't match the format of the data lines (i.e. 4 columns separated by tabs) then the data in them should be discarded.